# Using cmd on live laravel site to run php artisan commands

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have a laravel site on server also cpanel access. I want to run all artisian commands which can be run on local using composer as i want to install dependencies like image intervation etc please help me out. Otherwise i have to download whole project to local.

Comment: Check This.... https://joshmountain.com/blog/installing-laravel-and-composer-on-a-cpanel-server

Comment: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9694/29/how-to-install-laravel-on-our-server

Answer (score 0):

if you have a good host then you might have a SSH option in your cpanal , if you can get the credentials from the host then you do what you want, but you will have a very limited access.I not sure you will be able to use all commands or not. if u want to use every thing try

https://forge.laravel.com/

or

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

or

https://www.digitalocean.com

Comment: Cpanel is giving me an option SSH option.